# Skipping variable looks impossible

Tags: variables, batch-file, echo

So I want to  Echo %%a into another txt file, but seems nothing works to me.
Here's the code :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
'dir "*.txt" /b /s /a-d' 
) do Echo for /f "delims=" %%a in ^( >> "%%a"
```

Simple : output file looks like:

> "for /f "delims=" C:\Documents and
>   Settings\xxxxx\Desktop\alpha\lol.txt in ( " .

I just need not a full path but "**%%a**". Bat file.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and what errors or problems you are experiencing?

Comment: Please state your question more precise (e.g. what are you trying to accomplish, which language are you using) and change the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: Simple : output file looks like: "for /f "delims=" C:\Documents and Settings\Skaarj\Desktop\alpha\lol.txt in ( " . I  just need not a full path but  "%%a". Bat file.

Answer (score 1):

You want the literal `%%a` ?

Try `%%%%a`

---

Second suggestion:

Try `%%%%^a`

Third - change the metavariable (loop-control variable) to `%%b`

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ( 
'dir "*.txt" /b /s /a-d' 
) do Echo for /f "delims=" %%%%a in ^( >> "%%b"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already tried this. It prints %C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxx\Desktop\alpha\lol.txt instead of %%a.

Comment: Thank you  ! your third suggestion works fine, now it's printed correctly as it should be :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*.txt" /b /s /a-d' ) do Echo %%a >> output.txt
```

Comment: Yes, %%a Echoes corectly, but when I want to Echo full function, it replaces %%a with full path.

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, it's not directly possible to escape the `%%a` expression in a loop.

But like Magoo mention, it can be solved with changing the loop parameter.

You could also use the parser to create the `%%a` output.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "static=for /f "delims=" %%%%a in ("
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 'dir "*.txt" /b /s /a-d') do (
  echo !static! >> "%%a"
)
```

The content of the variable `static` will be expanded, but the inner `%%a` will not expanded later.

Comment: It's very useful ! I've been searching this for ages.